# 400 bad request when logging/pushing npm package to nexus?

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, nexus

I am trying to use a private `npm` registry for my nodejs projects and I am using nexus for that matter. I kept `admin` user to be used, at least for testing and to guarantee there's no permission issue. However, I can login neither publish using `npm login --registry <private-registry-address>` and `npm publish --registry <private-registry-address>` receptively. I used several methods, first I manually added entries in `.npmrc` file as follows:

**This one is mentioned in Nexus 3 docs:**

```
➜  echo "email=$NPM_EMAIL" > $HOME/.npmrc                                       
➜  echo "_auth=$(echo -n "$NPM_USER:$NPM_PASS" | openssl base64)" >> $HOME/.npmrc
➜  echo "always-auth=true" >> $HOME/.npmrc
```

Then I try to publish using `npm publish --registry http://172.17.0.1:8081/repository/npmtest/`, but it just gives me:

```
npm ERR! code E400
npm ERR! 400 Bad Request - PUT http://172.17.0.1:8081/repository/npmtest/mypackage
```

**This one is kind of the official in npm docs:**

Here, I log in the repo using the credentials I have as follows:

```
➜  npm login --registry http://172.17.0.1:8081/repository/npmtest/
```

and enter my login creds:

```
Username: admin
Password: 
Email: (this IS public) admin@example.org
```

But unfortunately, it gives me the same exact error:

```
npm ERR! code E400
npm ERR! 400 Bad Request - PUT http://localhost:8081/repository/npmtest/-/user/org.couchdb.user:admin
```

I have added `npm Bearer Token Realm` in Nexus as I saw in many discussions and it didn't make a difference as well.

I have tried to use another repo `verdaccio` and it worked normally, that's why I am pretty sure this is a nexus issue.

**Note: I am using all repo managers (Nexus and verdaccio) as docker containers, anyway this should not be an issue.**

I am running `npm` version `6.10`

What could be a solution here for nexus to work?

Comment: Which version of `npm` are you running? Could the package version already be deployed and it's now preventing you from re-publishing?

Comment: @jcragun `6.10` is the npm version. There is nothing there in the repo.

Answer (score 4):

```js
{
  ...,
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "<linkToNexusRepo>"
  }
}
```

Resolve the issue for me by adding this snipped in my `package.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have selected the correct format and type for the repository. In my case I accidentally created the npm repository with the incorrect format.

I created a `Format: nuget` instead of `Format: npm`.

You can see the format when you select the repository in the Nexus dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, we have to keep same npmrc line of code at both place

- `$HOME/.npmrc`
- Project `.npmrc` at root level

  ```
  registry=http://172.17.0.1:8081/repository/npmtest/mypackage/npm/registry/

  always-auth=true

  ; begin auth token // remove in the case of $HOME/.npmrc
  //repository/npmtest/mypackage/npm/registry/:username=****
  //repository/npmtest/mypackage/npm/registry/:_password=${NPM_TOKEN}
  //repository/npmtest/mypackage/npm/registry/:email=*****
  //repository/npmtest/mypackage/npm/:username=****
  //repository/npmtest/mypackage/npm/:_password=${NPM_TOKEN}
  //repository/npmtest/mypackage/npm/:email=*****

  ; end auth token // remove in the case of $HOME/.npmrc
  ```

It will surely work ;)

Answer (score -2):

You should either choose your local registry in your command explicitly, or do a one time config like below:

```
npm config set registry http://localhost:port
```

Example for explicit registry without using above command:

```
npm adduser --registry http://localhost:port
```